# Monitor Number of Requests in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

If I have a specific link in my sinatra, for instance say /requests, how can I monitor the number of times the page is loaded.  Ideally, I want to be able to get a hit count for how many times a specific page on my server is accessed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of ways to do this. For example, you could add a [filters](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters) which can log this.

To log the request you can use file system, database, etc. Something like below.

```
#filter to intercept request to URL
before '/requests' do
  log_request
end
# Helper function to write
def log_request
  # Actual logic to write to file system or database
end
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed in this scenario.